# Customize the UI of dotnet Health Checks

Tags: css, .net-core, health-check

I have configured the health checks for my dotnet api using Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks. For one of my health checks my tag contains a big string because of which it is not visible properly. Basically the text is cutting down from the coloured background of the Tag cells. Is there a way to change the size of the Tag columns in the health checks UI.

So the Tags column is a flex when adding multiple tags with long text it is overflowing outside if one tag and in case of multiple tags it is overflowing/overlapping to the next flex.

```
.hc-checks-table__body td > * {
    display: flex;
}
```

Any help!!!!